# не выделяется нормально элемент в gtk

Tags: linux, c, gtk3, gtk+

вот какой вид сделал.
[image: items]
хотелось бы чтобы при клике по элементу, он выделялся. главный виджет элемента это frame. в него уже вставлены box и другие frame. у меня получилось сделать только чтобы выделялся текстовый виджет и выделяется полностью виджет элемент только последний, да и то, когда кликаешь по тексту. я уже не знаю что пробовал. заглянул в код transmission-gtk, но там вроде сделано с помощью tree_view виджета и элементы, такие как текст используются как cell. но в моем случае есть виджеты frame, то которые с названиями ELF, PE, BIN и frame красные с обозначением что выбирается для процессоров intel и amd. я хотел сделать красивое оформление, чтобы радовало глаз и отличалось от других подобных программ. что можно сделать, чтобы виджеты остались такими же, но можно было заменить фон виджета на например посветлее. я пробовал указать frame#frame:hover, но это не работает. также как и не работает событие event при клике по элементу. подскажите а. вот код.
**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include "words.h"

GtkApplication *app;
GtkWidget *open_bin_window;
GMenu *app_menu;
char **word;

struct widgets_langages {
} wl;
const int size_wl = 0;

static gboolean open_bin_window_delete_event_cb ( GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data ) {
    gtk_widget_hide ( open_bin_window );
    return TRUE;
}

static gboolean app_window_delete_event_cb ( GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data ) {
    g_application_quit ( ( GApplication * ) app );
    exit ( EXIT_SUCCESS );
    return FALSE;
}

static void action_open_bin_cb ( GSimpleAction *action, GVariant *parameter, gpointer data ) {
    gtk_widget_show_all ( open_bin_window );
}

static void action_show_settings_cb ( GSimpleAction *action, GVariant *parameter, gpointer data ) {
}

const GActionEntry entries[] = {
    { "action_open_bin", action_open_bin_cb, NULL, NULL, NULL },
    { "action_settings", action_show_settings_cb, NULL, NULL, NULL }
};

static void create_actions ( GtkWindow *window ) {
    g_action_map_add_action_entries ( ( GActionMap * ) window, entries, G_N_ELEMENTS ( entries ), NULL );
}

static void create_app_menu ( ) {
    int index = 0;
    g_menu_append ( app_menu, word[0], "win.action_open_bin" );
    g_menu_append ( app_menu, word[1], "win.action_settings" );

}

static void switch_language_cb ( ) {
    g_menu_remove_all ( app_menu );
    create_app_menu ( );
}

GtkWidget *box_select_bin_0;
static void elf_intel_linux_read ( ) {
}
static void pe_intel_windows_read ( ) {
}
static void bin_intel_read ( ) {
}

struct select_items {
    GtkWidget *widget;
    GtkWidget *text_view;
    GtkWidget *box;
} si[3];
int count_si = 0;


static gboolean text_view_info_bin_draw_cb ( GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, gpointer data ) {
        gtk_widget_queue_resize ( widget );
        return FALSE;
}

static gboolean text_view_item_select_bin_event_cb ( GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data ) {
    GdkEventType type = event->type;
    switch ( type ) {
        case GDK_BUTTON_PRESS:
            {
                for ( int i = 0; i < count_si; i++ ) {
                    if ( si[i].text_view == widget ) {
                        printf ( "text_view selected\n" );
                        gtk_widget_set_name ( widget, "info_bin_selected" );
                        gtk_widget_set_name ( si[i].widget, "item_bin_selected" );
                    }
                    else {
                        gtk_widget_set_name ( widget, "info_bin" );
                        gtk_widget_set_name ( si[i].widget, "item_bin" );
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
static gboolean frame_main_select_bin_event_cb ( GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data ) {
    GdkEventType type = event->type;
    switch ( type ) {
        case GDK_BUTTON_PRESS:
            {
                printf ( "frame button press\n" );
                for ( int i = 0; i < count_si; i++ ) {
                    if ( si[i].widget == widget ) {
                        printf ( "frame selected\n" );
                        gtk_widget_set_name ( widget, "item_bin_selected" );
                        gtk_widget_set_name ( si[i].text_view, "info_bin_selected" );
                    }
                    else {
                        gtk_widget_set_name ( widget, "item_bin" );
                        gtk_widget_set_name ( si[i].text_view, "info_bin" );
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

static void add_item ( GtkWidget *box_items, const char *label, const char *info, void (*func) (void), const int count, ... ) {
    GtkWidget *frame_main = g_object_new ( GTK_TYPE_FRAME, "shadow-type", GTK_SHADOW_NONE, "name", "item_bin", NULL );

    GtkWidget *frame_label = g_object_new ( GTK_TYPE_FRAME, "shadow-type", GTK_SHADOW_NONE, "name", "item_label", NULL );
    gtk_widget_set_size_request ( frame_label, 64, 64 );

    gtk_widget_set_margin_start ( frame_label, 5 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_end ( frame_label, 5 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_top ( frame_label, 5 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_bottom ( frame_label, 5 );

    GtkWidget *label_label = gtk_label_new ( label );
    gtk_widget_set_name ( label_label, "label_bin" );

    gtk_widget_set_margin_start ( label_label, 14 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_end ( label_label, 14 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_top ( label_label, 14 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_bottom ( label_label, 14 );

    gtk_container_add ( ( GtkContainer * ) frame_label, label_label );

    GtkWidget *main_box = gtk_box_new ( GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0 );
    gtk_container_add ( ( GtkContainer * ) frame_main, main_box );

    gtk_box_pack_start ( ( GtkBox * ) main_box, frame_label, FALSE, FALSE, 0 );

    GtkWidget *box_cpu = gtk_box_new ( GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 5 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_start ( box_cpu, 4 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_end ( box_cpu, 4 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_top ( box_cpu, 4 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_bottom ( box_cpu, 4 );

    va_list ap;
    va_start ( ap, count );
    for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
        char *l = va_arg ( ap, char * );
        GtkWidget *label_cpu = gtk_label_new ( l );
        gtk_widget_set_name ( label_cpu, "label_cpu" );

        gtk_widget_set_margin_start ( label_cpu, 4 );
        gtk_widget_set_margin_end ( label_cpu, 4 );
        gtk_widget_set_margin_top ( label_cpu, 2 );
        gtk_widget_set_margin_bottom ( label_cpu, 2 );

        GtkWidget *fr = g_object_new ( GTK_TYPE_FRAME, "shadow-type", GTK_SHADOW_NONE, "name", "item_cpu", NULL );
        gtk_container_add ( ( GtkContainer * ) fr, label_cpu );

        gtk_box_pack_end ( ( GtkBox * ) box_cpu, fr, FALSE, FALSE, 0 );
    }
    va_end ( ap );

    GtkWidget *box_2 = gtk_box_new ( GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0 );
    gtk_box_pack_start ( ( GtkBox * ) box_2, box_cpu, FALSE, FALSE, 0 );

    gtk_box_pack_end ( ( GtkBox * ) main_box, box_2, TRUE, TRUE, 0 );

    GtkTextBuffer *buffer = gtk_text_buffer_new ( NULL );
    gtk_text_buffer_set_text ( buffer, info, strlen ( info ) );
    GtkWidget *text_view = gtk_text_view_new_with_buffer ( buffer );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_start ( text_view, 0 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_end ( text_view, 0 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_top ( text_view, 0 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_bottom ( text_view, 0 );
    gtk_text_view_set_wrap_mode ( ( GtkTextView * ) text_view, GTK_WRAP_WORD );
    gtk_text_view_set_editable ( ( GtkTextView * ) text_view, FALSE );
    gtk_widget_set_name ( text_view, "info_bin" );
    g_signal_connect ( text_view, "draw", G_CALLBACK ( text_view_info_bin_draw_cb ), NULL );

    GtkWidget *frame_text = g_object_new ( GTK_TYPE_FRAME, "shadow-type", GTK_SHADOW_NONE, "name", "text_info", NULL );
    gtk_container_add ( ( GtkContainer * ) frame_text, text_view );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_top ( frame_text, 4 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_end ( frame_text, 4 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_start ( frame_text, 4 );
    gtk_widget_set_margin_bottom ( frame_text, 4 );

    GtkWidget *box_info = gtk_box_new ( GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0 );
    gtk_box_pack_start ( ( GtkBox * ) box_info, frame_text, TRUE, TRUE, 0 );
    gtk_box_pack_start ( ( GtkBox * ) box_2, box_info, TRUE, TRUE, 0 );

    gtk_box_pack_start ( ( GtkBox * ) box_items, frame_main, FALSE, FALSE, 0 );

    g_signal_connect ( frame_main, "event", G_CALLBACK ( frame_main_select_bin_event_cb ), NULL );
    g_signal_connect ( text_view, "event", G_CALLBACK ( text_view_item_select_bin_event_cb ), NULL );
    si[count_si].widget = frame_main;
    si[count_si].text_view = text_view;
    count_si++;

}

static void init_open_bin_window ( GtkWindow *window ) {
    gtk_widget_set_name ( ( GtkWidget * ) window, "window_open_bin" );
    gtk_application_window_set_show_menubar ( ( GtkApplicationWindow * ) window, FALSE );
    gtk_window_set_default_size ( window, 600, 600 );
    g_signal_connect ( open_bin_window, "delete-event", G_CALLBACK ( open_bin_window_delete_event_cb ), NULL );

    box_select_bin_0 = gtk_box_new ( GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 10 );
    GtkWidget *box_items_0 = gtk_box_new ( GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 4 );
    GtkWidget *scroll_items_0 = gtk_scrolled_window_new ( NULL, NULL );

    add_item ( box_items_0, "ELF", "Выберите формат файлов предназначенных для линукс", elf_intel_linux_read, 2, "intel", "amd" );
    add_item ( box_items_0, "PE", "Выберите формат файлов предназначенных для windows", pe_intel_windows_read, 2, "intel", "amd" );
    add_item ( box_items_0, "BIN", "Выберите формат файлов не для ос", bin_intel_read, 2, "intel", "amd" );

    gtk_container_add ( ( GtkContainer * ) scroll_items_0, box_items_0 );

    gtk_box_pack_start ( ( GtkBox * ) box_select_bin_0, scroll_items_0, TRUE, TRUE, 0 );

    GtkWidget *button_next_0 = gtk_button_new_with_label ( word[7] );
    GtkWidget *box_buttons_0 = gtk_box_new ( GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0 );
    gtk_box_pack_end ( ( GtkBox * ) box_buttons_0, button_next_0, FALSE, FALSE, 0 );

    gtk_box_pack_end ( ( GtkBox * ) box_select_bin_0, box_buttons_0, FALSE, FALSE, 0 );

    gtk_container_add ( ( GtkContainer * ) open_bin_window, box_select_bin_0 );
    gtk_widget_hide ( open_bin_window );
}

const char *style = "window#window_open_bin { } frame#item_bin { background: #5c5c5c; border-radius: 6px; border-color: #000000; box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba ( 0, 0, 0, 0.8 ); } frame#item_label { background-color: #3c3c3c; border-radius: 6px; border-color: #000000; } label#label_bin { color: #ffff00; } frame#item_cpu { background-color: #ff0000; border-radius: 10px; } label#label_cpu { font-size: 8pt; color: #ffffff; } textview#info_bin * { color: #ffffff; background-color: #5c5c5c; } textview#info_bin_selected * { color: #ffffff; background-color: #8c8c8c; } frame#text_info { background-color: #5c5c5c; } frame#item_bin_selected { background: #8c8c8c; border-radius: 6px; border-color: #000000; } button:hover { background: #ff0000; }";
GtkTreeStore *store_dynamic;

enum {
    DYNAMIC_ADDRESS,
    DYNAMIC_OPCODE,
    DYNAMIC_OPERATOR,
    DYNAMIC_COMMENTS,
    DYNAMIC_COUNT
};

static void get_store_dynamic ( GtkWidget *tree_static_view ) {
    store_dynamic = gtk_tree_store_new ( DYNAMIC_COUNT,
            G_TYPE_LONG,
            G_TYPE_STRING,
            G_TYPE_STRING,
            G_TYPE_STRING
            );

    GtkTreeViewColumn *column;
    GtkCellRenderer *renderer;

    const char *cells[] = {
        word[2],
        word[3],
        word[4],
        word[5]
    };

    for ( int i = 0; i < DYNAMIC_COUNT; i++ ) {
        renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new ( );
        column = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes ( cells[i], renderer, "text", i, NULL );
        gtk_tree_view_column_set_resizable ( column, TRUE );
        gtk_tree_view_append_column ( ( GtkTreeView * ) tree_static_view, column );
    }

    gtk_tree_view_set_model ( ( GtkTreeView * ) tree_static_view, ( GtkTreeModel * ) store_dynamic );
}

static void app_activate_cb ( GApplication *application, gpointer data ) {

    GtkWidget *app_window = gtk_application_window_new ( app );
    gtk_window_set_default_size ( ( GtkWindow * ) app_window, 1024, 600 );

    open_bin_window = gtk_application_window_new ( app );
    init_open_bin_window ( ( GtkWindow * ) open_bin_window );
    create_actions ( ( GtkWindow * ) app_window );
    app_menu = g_menu_new ( );
    create_app_menu ( );

    g_signal_connect ( app_window, "delete-event", G_CALLBACK ( app_window_delete_event_cb ), NULL );

    gtk_application_set_app_menu ( app, ( GMenuModel * ) app_menu );

    GtkWidget *header_bar = gtk_header_bar_new ( );
    gtk_header_bar_set_title ( ( GtkHeaderBar * ) header_bar, "cfdbg" );
    gtk_header_bar_set_show_close_button ( ( GtkHeaderBar * ) header_bar, TRUE );
    gtk_header_bar_set_decoration_layout ( ( GtkHeaderBar * ) header_bar, ":menu,minimize,maximize,close" );
    gtk_window_set_titlebar ( ( GtkWindow * ) app_window, header_bar );

    GdkDisplay *display = gdk_display_get_default ( );
    GdkScreen *screen = gdk_display_get_default_screen ( display );
    GtkCssProvider *css_provider = gtk_css_provider_new ( );

    gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen ( screen, ( GtkStyleProvider * ) css_provider, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION );
    gtk_css_provider_load_from_data ( css_provider, style, strlen ( style ), NULL );

    GtkStyleContext *style_context = gtk_style_context_new ( );
    gtk_style_context_add_provider ( style_context, ( GtkStyleProvider * ) css_provider, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER );

    GtkWidget *tree_dynamic_view = gtk_tree_view_new ( );

    get_store_dynamic ( tree_dynamic_view );

    GtkWidget *debug_dynamic_scroll = gtk_scrolled_window_new ( NULL, NULL );
    gtk_container_add ( ( GtkContainer * ) debug_dynamic_scroll, tree_dynamic_view );

    GtkWidget *dynamic_main_box = gtk_box_new ( GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0 );
    GtkWidget *dynamic_component_box = gtk_box_new ( GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0 );

    gtk_box_pack_start ( ( GtkBox * ) dynamic_component_box, debug_dynamic_scroll, TRUE, TRUE, 0 );
    gtk_box_pack_start ( ( GtkBox * ) dynamic_main_box, dynamic_component_box, FALSE, FALSE, 0 );

    GtkWidget *app_notebook = gtk_notebook_new ( );
    gtk_notebook_append_page ( ( GtkNotebook * ) app_notebook, dynamic_main_box, gtk_label_new ( word[6] ) );

    gtk_container_add ( ( GtkContainer * ) app_window, app_notebook );
    gtk_widget_show_all ( app_window );
}

int main ( int argc, char **argv ) {
    word = calloc ( 0, sizeof ( char * ) );
    init_words ( );

    app = gtk_application_new ( "com.xverizex.cfdbg", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE );
    g_application_register ( ( GApplication * ) app, NULL, NULL );
    g_signal_connect ( app, "activate", G_CALLBACK ( app_activate_cb ), NULL );
    return g_application_run ( ( GApplication * ) app, argc, argv );
}
```

**words.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

extern char **word;
static int index_str = 0;
static int size = 0;

void init_words ( ) {
    char path[255];
    snprintf ( path, 255, "assets/language/en.lng" );
    FILE *fp = fopen ( path, "r" );

    char *line = calloc ( 4096, 1 );

    while ( fgets ( line, 4096, fp ) ) {
        size++;
        word = realloc ( word, sizeof ( char * ) * size );
        int length = strlen ( line );
        word[index_str] = calloc ( length + 1, 1 );
        strncpy ( word[index_str], line, length );
        index_str++;
    }

    fclose ( fp );
    free ( line );
}
```

**words.h**

```
#ifndef __WORDS__
#define __WORDS__
void init_words ( );
#endif
```

Comment: я немного исправил у себя в коде, но здесь не добавил изменения. теперь виджет нормально закрашивается, но только если я кликаю по виджету text_view. а сам frame не реагирует.

Answer (score 0):

всё сделал. я подписался на события окна и проверяю клики по позициям. я не знаю насколько это правильно. ведь я не знаю что будет, когда виджет уйдет за край scroll_window. но в этом случае проблема возникает если кликнуть по виджету text_view, конечно можно было заменить на простой label, но вдруг будет много текста, а этот виджет переносит слова на следующую строку. в общем я оставил подписку на события для text_view, и если кликаешь по text_view, то виджет закрашивается, и дальше событие клика не передается, потому что возвращаю TRUE.

Comment: Всё и с областью scroll справился. просто проверяю размер scroll. если кликаешь за scroll, то выход из функции.